# Declaring Function invalid character in identifier Python

Tags: python-3.x

I've been coding in python 2 for a long time and recently upgraded to python 3. Suddenly I'm getting an invalid character in identifier error when declaring a function. I'm changing this from python 2 to python 3, but I didn't think this would be an issue...

```
def getValid(theQuestion, theMin, theMax):
```

It's saying there's an invalid syntax on the first open parenthesis.
Any tips?

Comment: I guess it could be a previous line, not this one...

Comment: There isn't anything on the previous line

Comment: Then paste the whole code so that others could recreate the error. This syntax is perfectly valid.

Answer (score 0):

The line as such is perfectly valid Python 3 code. I'm guessing your problem is of some completely different nature, such as some accidentally inserted invisible Unicode character (like a UTF-8-encoded byte-order indicator), or a non-breaking space instead of an ordinary space, or some line-ending confusion or some such thing.

It might help if you look at the file with `cat -A` or a hex editor or something like that in order to make sure there's nothing weird hiding in there. (Or simply use a proper, well-adjusted text editor.)